# Creating a SQL view with personal best records

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have the following SQL Database structure:

[image: Database model]

Users are the registered users. Maps are like circuits or race tracks. When a user is driving a time a new time record will be created including the userId, mapId and the time needed to finish the racetrack.

I wish to create a view where all the users personal bests on all maps are listed.

I tried creating the view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW map_pb AS
SELECT MID, UID, TID
FROM times
WHERE score IN (SELECT MIN(score) FROM times)
ORDER BY registered
```

This does not lead to the wished result.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the `score` here is it the race_time of a particular user on a map or some points gained on each race?
Also Since your granular level is UID, remove MID since you want personal bests on all maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you have 'times' table created as the above diagram and 'score' column in the table that you use to measure the best record.
(MIN(score) is the best record).

You can simply create a view to have the personal best records using sub-queries like this.

```
CREATE VIEW map_pb AS
SELECT a.MID, a.UID, a.TID
FROM times a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TID, UID, MIN(score) score
    FROM times 
    GROUP BY UID
) b ON a.UID = b.UID AND a.score= b.score
-- if you have 'registered' column in the 'times' table to order the result
ORDER BY registered
```

I hope this may work.

Comment: The inner join only required an additional MID in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a query that will first return the minimum score for each user on each map.  Something like this:

```
SELECT  UID,
        MID,
        MIN(score) AS best_time
  FROM  times
  GROUP BY UID, MID
```

Note: I used `MIN(score)` as this is what is shown in your example query, but perhaps it should be `MIN(time)` instead?

Then just use the subquery `JOIN`ed to your other tables to get the output:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  (
        SELECT  UID,
                MID,
                MIN(score) AS best_time
          FROM  times
          GROUP BY UID, MID
        ) a
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.UID = a.UID
    INNER JOIN maps m ON m.MID = a.MID
```

Of course, replace `SELECT *` with the columns you actually want.

Note: code untested but does give an idea as to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a subquery to determine each user's minimum score on each map

```
         SELECT UID, TID, MIN(time) time
           FROM times
          GROUP BY UID, TID
```

Then join that subquery into a main query.

```
 SELECT times.UID, times.TID, 
        mintimes.time
   FROM times
   JOIN (
        ) mintimes   ON times.TID = mintimes.TID
                    AND times.UID = mintimes.UID
                    AND times.time = mintimes.time
   JOIN maps ON times.MID = maps.MID
   JOIN users ON times.UID = users.UID
```

This query pattern uses a `GROUP BY` function to find the outlying (MIN in this case) value for each combination.  It then uses that subquery to find the detail record for each outlying value.